# Компоновка компонентов в activity

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть `Activity` (не диалог!). На которой нужно расположить компоненты - `TextView`, `EditView` и две `Button`, - следующим образом:

[image]

Пробовал использовать `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout` в разных комбинациях, устанавливал `setMinimumWidth`, и т.д. Ничего не помогло. Все равно получается вот такой layout:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Были аналогичные проблемы. Очевидно, вы не используете параметр layout_weight. [Вот](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328) замечательная ссылка, по который вы разберётесь с "весами" (она же помогла мне). Вам нужно установить одинаковые веса для обоих кнопок по 1.

Comment: Классно! Думаю, поможет. Я пишу с помошью java-кода, а не через xml, правда. Но это не должно помешать :)

Comment: Вообще говоря, лучше то что можно вынести в xml - выносить в xml, так как Вам же проще будет. Кроме того с помощью плагина ADT в Eclipse можно быстро прототипировать интерфейс, посмотрев как он будет выглядеть.

Comment: Да, в xml лучше и наглядней...